# Android - Match parent height, adjust width to maintain aspect ratio in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, width, aspect-ratio

I have a horizontal scroll view that contains an ImageView followed by a horizontal LinearLayout (with child views).  When I receive the ImageView from an API, I want it to be able to match parent in terms of height, then expand in terms of width to maintain aspect ratio.  How should I configure the ImageView to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to simply specify `match_parent` for height and `wrap_content` for width? The parent with the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Set the height of the ImageView to `match_parent` so it matches the height of the parent. Then just calculate the width based on the aspect ratio you're trying to achieve, e.g. -- 16:9 = height/0.5625.  -- and set the width to that.

**EDIT:**
To get the target height, then calculate the target width based on that value, you would first get the height of the parent layout, then calculate the width, then set the LayoutParams of your ImageView, then add the view. Something like this...

```
RelativeLayout parentLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
int height = parentLayout.getHeight();
int targetWidth = (int)Math.round(height / 0.5625); //example for 16:9 ratio
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
     targetWidth,
     ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
));
parentLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: What if I don't know the aspect ration? I'm expecting different types of images.

Comment: Then use `wrap_content` for the width after setting the height to `match_parent`, and the ImageView should size itself the correct width after you've set the height.

Comment: This does not work. Those values always have to be defined. You can just set one then set the other.

Comment: You don't set them one after another. You would retrieve the parent's height first, then do your calculations, then set everything at once. See my edit above.